# Meaning of 職員室に叩き出される

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

When reading something I came across the following line:

> まずいな。職員室**に叩き出される**ぞ

However I was not quite sure how to understand 叩き出される in this context. I think I understand the usage of 叩き出される when used with から e.g. 職員室から叩き出される(thrown/kicked out of the staff room), however when used with に I am not quite sure how to understand it. In the passage they were worried that what they were doing was going to be found out.

Comment: This seems to need more context. Is the said person actually got "in" the room or "out"? Or totally unrelated to the actual room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should just mean "thrown/kicked **into** the teachers' room".
Assuming the speaker is a student, he said this because the teachers' room is psychologically an unfamiliar "outside" place to the students. Of course something like 職員室に放り込まれるぞ is equally correct, but we somehow don't say 職員室に叩き入れる.

**EDIT:** "Outside" may not have been the best word to describe this 出る. 出る can refer to going to a stage, a battlefield, the firing line (of criticism), etc., so I think this 出される was used to imply something stressful was waiting in the room.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the expression 「職員室に叩き出される」 here is a variation on (or at least the 「出される」part is influenced by) the more common「職員室に呼び出される」 ("to be called into the staffroom").

Students may 職員室に呼び出される for various reasons, both good and bad, but more often than not it spells trouble for them.

The meaning of the 「叩き出される」 in this case would be much the same as that of「呼び出される」, but with the indication of the speaker's belief that it wouldn't be for a good reason and the person who is going to call them into the staffroom will be very angry with them.

Comment: 単に校内放送とかで呼ばれた時に「やべー職員室に叩き出されたよ」とか言うことってあります？　この「叩き出される」には「嫌だろうけどほら行って来い」という感じで誰かに背中を押される感じを受けるのですが。「蹴り出される」「突き出される」と同じ感じの。（「鬼教官の前に叩き出される」みたいな言い方はするので、職員室の中の怖い人物を想像して言っているということはあるのかも…）

Comment: @naruto & goldbrick そもそも僕の語感だとこのコロケーションが解釈できないんですが（「鬼教官～」の例はわかります）、そのような意味だとすると「職員室」や「叩き出す人々（誰？）」のイメージが日常思い浮かべるものと比べてかなり異様なものに感じてしまいます。そうであれば、ほかにも「職員室」が何かの換喩であるとか、「叩き出す」が特殊な文脈における特定の動作を表すという可能性も考えられると思うのですがどうでしょうか…

Comment: @naruto 慣用的な表現ではなく、即席的な造語の一種でになると言えると思います。「叩き-」は主に「荒々しさ」および「無理矢理さ」の意味を付加する役割を担うものだと思います。主意において「突き出される」と重なるという見解ですが、これはその通りで、僕の見落しでした。「叩き出す」が第三者の行為であって何ら不整合はないはずです。有力な解釈だと思います。「叩き」は良いとして、「出される」の部分の意味が不透明で、文脈を頼りに代替可能と思える既成表現を求めて「呼び出される」にまず辿り着いたのですが、もう少し思索を続けるべきでした。

Comment: @broken laptop 「職員室」が換喩的な指示性を持つというのは、僕も「に」が場所ではなく行為主を示すものである可能性を考えたときに作動した解釈なのですが、もしかしてそういう事でしょうか。結局は他方の解釈と比べるとやはり特殊すぎて可能性が薄く感じられたので放棄してしまいましたが果たして・・・